# Codeigniter urls solution

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have problem with codeigniter url . I add images folder into CI. But when i try to load i get 404
i used mode rewrite and set default controler to pages

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

set base url to

```
 $config['base_url']    = '';
```

and i get still http://{localhost}/zadatak/pages/images/Search.png 404 (Not Found)

when i type

```
<img src="<?php site_url()?>images/Search.png" />
```

why pages from url isnt removed?

Comment: why you set base_url to empty string? base_url and site_url is not the same, try using base_url() instead. Take a look at [this](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/113974/#996807)

Comment: where is your image directory located in your app?

Answer (score 0):

better way to load images in CI is to use img helper function, if you want load images with helper function you can use base_url helper method you need to define base_url in config too. problem with site_url is if you use url_sufix in config like as .html or .page it will add this at end of image extension and you will get 404 error again.

**with img helper method**

```
<?php echo img('images/search.png') ?>
```

**with base_url**

```
<img href="<?=base_url("images/search.png")?>"
```

html way for base url
you can define base tag in html head tag, giving path of your image directory

```
<html>
 <head>
    <base href="<?=base_url("images/")?>"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction.

1. Your image directory should location in the root of your application like:

   -- images
   -- application
   -- system
2. You should load the [URL helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all confirm where your images folder is located if it is located at root where there is your application and system directory.

Then instead of site_url() use base_url().

For example :

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/search.png">
```

Let me know if you have further doubts.

Regards,
Zeeshan.